# Utilizar o objeto Application do Excel dentro do Access

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, microsoft-access

Estou criando um script em VBA que exporta uma tabela em várias planilhas compartilhadas do excel em um diretório específico.

O problema é que o Excel emite um aviso para confirmação do salvamento do arquivo para cada arquivo.

Gostaria de suprimir essa confirmação. Utilizando o VBA diretamente em macros do excel é possível fazer o seguinte:

```
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
```

Alguém sabe como utilizar o objeto `Application` a partir da instância dessa planilha dentro do Access ou de alguma outra forma de salvar esse arquivo ?

Trecho de código que gera as planihas:

```
Private Function formataPlanilha(path As String)

    Dim workbook As Excel.workbook
    Dim sheet As Excel.Worksheet

    Set workbook = Excel.Application.Workbooks.Open(path)

    If workbook.MultiUserEditing Then
        workbook.ExclusiveAccess
        workbook.Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    End If

    Set sheet = workbook.Sheets(1)

    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

    With sheet
        Call Formata_Planilha_Faltas
    End With

    workbook.Saved = True
    workbook.SaveAs Filename:=path, AccessMode:=xlShared, ConflictResolution:=Excel.XlSaveConflictResolution.xlLocalSessionChanges

ErrorHandler:
    workbook.Close

End Function
```

**Nota:** Como o comando `DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport` não salva o arquivo exportado como compartilhado, tenho que abrir novamente a planilha no objeto excel, aplicar algumas formatações e salvar como compartilhado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O código do VBA do Excel pode ser utilizado da mesma forma de dentro do Access, ou do Word, ou de qualquer outro aplicativo do Office.

Primeiramente, deve-se importar a biblioteca do Excel para o script escrito no outro programa, no caso, o Access. No editor `Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications`, vá até o menu `Ferramentas` (Tools), depois `Referências` (References). Lá, localize e marque o item `Microsoft Excel XX Object Library`, onde XX é a versão do Excel. Dê um OK.

Em seguida, dentro do seu código do Access, basta criar uma nova instância do Excel, e referenciá-la de acordo:

```
Sub Exemplo()
    Dim excelApp As Excel.Application
    Set excelApp = New Excel.Application

    'Se atribuir True, a janela do Excel aparecerá
    excelApp.Visible = False


    'Coloque seu código aqui, substituindo Excel.Application por excelApp
    '...


    'Termina o Excel
    excelApp.Quit
End Sub
```